# Document on change class, picking up both elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onchange

I have a HTML form block that is included twice on the same page. This is done because one is on the page, and one is within a modal.

The form has a select element with class of `.select_one`. So because of the form being included twice onto the page, there are two elements with the class `.select_one`.

I have a document change check through jQuery.

```
 $(document).on("change", '.select_one', function (e) {
        var select_one = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {select_one: select_one},
            url: '../../ajax/change_select_two.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (json) {
                console.log(json);
                var $el = $("select.select_two");
                $el.each(function() {

                    var $select_picker = $(this);
                    $select_picker.empty(); // remove old options
                    $select_picker.append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value", '0').text('Please Select Two'));
                    $.each(json, function (value, data) {
                        $select_picker.append($("<option></option>")
                            .attr("value", data['Model']).text(ucwords(data['Text'].replace(/_/g, ' '))));
                    });
                    $select_picker.selectpicker('refresh');
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

This sends an Ajax request based on the value of the select option, to return some values and populate another select option within the form.

When I change one of the forms `.select_one`, it is running this document change function twice (once for each `.select_one') rather than just for the one that is being changed.

Why would this happen, and what is the best solution to it?

Comment: The code quoted in your question will not do that, I'm afraid you've probably taken the M in [mcve] a bit too far. My guess is that within the handler you've done `$(".select_one").xyz` and then done something with that set. Don't do that, use `$(this).xyz` instead. `this` is a reference to the one `.select_one` element related to the `change`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Updated the question. I did use $(this) but it didnt work.

Comment: It definitely isn't running the handler twice. But in your handler, are you really sure you want to do `var $el = $("select.select_two");` and then loop through `$el` (which will have as many elements as there are `select`s with the class `select_two`)?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The ajax request is getting fired twice. That means the handler is running twice, no?

Answer (score 0):

In a comment on the question, you've said:

> The ajax request is getting fired twice.

The code in your question, if run just once, will not fire the handler more than once when a single `select` is changed.

So that tells us one of two things is happening:

1. The code in your question is running more than once, or
2. Something is generating a second `change` event when the first `change` event is received

#### Running your code more than once

In this scenario, the code in your question is being run *more than once*, which will hook up a new handler each time, like this:

```js
function hookUp() {
  $(document).on("change", ".select_one", function() {
    console.log("Handler fired");
  });
}
hookUp();
hookUp();
```

```html
<select class="select_one">
  <option>This</option>
  <option>That</option>
  <option>The Other</option>
</select>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now, you're clearly not doing something so obvious as `hookUp(); hookUp();`, but *something* is calling your

```
$(document).on("change", '.select_one', function (e) {
    // ...
});
```

code twice.

#### Generating a `change` event

Something is causing a second `change` event to be generated when processing the first `change` event; for instance, perhaps something associated with the `select_two` select box that gets updated.

My synthetic example for this is even more obviously not what's really happening, but for illustration:

```js
var synthetic = 0;
$(document).on("change", ".select_one", function() {
  console.log("Handler fired");
  if (!synthetic) {
    ++synthetic;
    $(this).change();
    --synthetic;
  }
});
```

```html
<select class="select_one">
  <option>This</option>
  <option>That</option>
  <option>The Other</option>
</select>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have two **.select_one** and for sure two **.select_two**

```
$(document).on('change', '.select_one', function(e){
    var select_one = $(this).val();

    // Your problem solved here
    var $el = $(this).closest('form').find('select.select_two');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {select_one: select_one},
        url: '../../ajax/change_select_two.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (json) {
            console.log(json);
            $el.each(function() {
                var $select_picker = $(this);
                $select_picker.empty(); // remove old options
                $select_picker.append($('<option></option>')
                    .attr('value', '0').text('Please Select Two'));
                $.each(json, function (value, data) {
                    $select_picker.append($('<option></option>')
                        .attr('value', data['Model']).text(ucwords(data['Text'].replace(/_/g, ' '))));
                });
                $select_picker.selectpicker('refresh');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Sometimes, people needs a comment to understand a down-vote.

Comment: My issue isn't that its putting the results into both select_two, but rather that the handler is firing twice (2 ajax requests are being sent).

Comment: Are you using clone to generate the modal form?

Comment: No. I've used a PHP include to include the file containing the form.

Comment: Can you please try `$('.select_one').on('change', function(){` **instead of** `$(document).on('change', '.select_one', function(e){` ? just 4 my curiosity.